# Combining relationship sorting and filtering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have two models: Item and Category. The Item model has a category_id field which is a foreign key of the category.

On the search page I am currently performing filtering. This is done via a series of `where()` clauses, for example

```
if($request->input('location_id', "") != "") {
    $query->where('location_id', '=', $request->input('location_id'));
}
```

These are contained within the scope search(), so they are called like this:

```
$results = Item::search($request)->get();
```

I now want to apply sorting to the results, firstly by the `name` column of the category, then by the `product_number` column on the items table.

How would I go about doing this without interfering with the filtering in the `search` scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add multiple calls to **orderBy()**:

```
$results = Item::search($request)
  ->join('categories', 'category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
  ->select('items.*')
  ->orderBy('categories.name')
  ->orderBy('product_number')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that sort by the name column of the item though? I need it to sort by the name column of the category.

Comment: You're right, I missed that you want to order by category's name. You'll need to explicitely join your items with their category. I've updated the answer